# XPATHS in Python with Selenium are Not Being Found

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

So I am trying to login to a Website using Python and Selenium. 
However, the problem is if I use the actual website I get a Blank Screen and none of the elements are detectable or found. I suspect that I am not waiting long enough for the page to load. But I am not sure that's correct either. I use a parent URL that redirected me to there and it loaded in a new tab with the Chromium Web driver. My problem is how do I log in, I have tried numerous methods, but none of them succeed.

The Parent URL: https://www.texasassessment.com/

If I click on the STAAR Portal button it takes me to the Child URL, which is what I am trying to login to.

The Child URL (Redirect): https://tx-login.ets.org/oaam_server/login.do

If I code the Child URL to be the main one for the Get statement, it never loads and just stays white.

[image]

That's if I code it with `browser.get("https://tx-login.ets.org/oaam_server/login.do")`

However if I go to the parent URL: https://www.texasassessment.com/

And follow the clicks to the actual Child URL, it will open a new link.
The code to pull up the Child URL directly:

```
import selenium
import shutil
import xlsxwriter
import os
import unittest
import requests
import getpass
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from datetime import date

import json
with open('secrets.json','r') as f:
          config = json.load(f)

          # Definitions
          # find_elements_by_name
          # find_elements_by_xpath
          # find_elements_by_link_text
          # find_elements_by_partial_link_text
          # find_elements_by_tag_name
          # find_elements_by_class_name
          # find_elements_by_css_selector

          # System Variables
          today = date.today()
          date = today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
          username = getpass.getuser()

          # URL Variables
          login_url = ''
          redirect_url = ''

          # WebDriver Path for Windows 10
          browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")

          # Parent URL
          browser.get("https://tx-login.ets.org/oaam_server/login.do")

          # Credentials NEEDS TO BE ENCRYPTED AND NOT BAKED INTO THE SCRIPT NEEDS UNIT TEST
          username = browser.find_element_by_id("Username")
          password = browser.find_element_by_id("Password")
          username.send_keys(config['user']['name'])
          password.send_keys(config['user']['password'])

          # Authentication submit.click()
          # For XPATH = //*[@id='qa-button-login']
          element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
                          EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='qa-button-login']")))
          element.click();
```

The code that navigates there and loads the actual page:

```
import selenium
import shutil
import xlsxwriter
import os
import unittest
import requests
import getpass
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from datetime import date

import json
with open('secrets.json','r') as f:
          config = json.load(f)

          # Definitions
          # find_elements_by_name
          # find_elements_by_xpath
          # find_elements_by_link_text
          # find_elements_by_partial_link_text
          # find_elements_by_tag_name
          # find_elements_by_class_name
          # find_elements_by_css_selector

          # System Variables
          today = date.today()
          date = today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
          username = getpass.getuser()

          # URL Variables
          login_url = ''
          redirect_url = ''

          # WebDriver Path for Windows 10
          browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")

          # Parent URL
          browser.get("https://www.texasassessment.com/administrators/")

          # Click on Star Portal 
          # For XPATH = /html/body/div[2]/section[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/a[3]
          element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
                          EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/section[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/a[3]")))
          element.click();

          # Credentials NEEDS TO BE ENCRYPTED AND NOT BAKED INTO THE SCRIPT NEEDS UNIT TEST
          username = browser.find_element_by_id("Username")
          password = browser.find_element_by_id("Password")
          username.send_keys(config['user']['name'])
          password.send_keys(config['user']['password'])

          # Authentication submit.click()
          # For XPATH = //*[@id='qa-button-login']
          element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
                          EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='qa-button-login']")))
          element.click();
```

All in all the page never loads, and/or if the redirect occurs the Elements and XPATHS are never found. 
What I am trying to is login to this page with Python and Selenium: https://tx-login.ets.org/oaam_server/login.do

Comment: Which element are you exactly referring as **STAAR Portal button**?

Comment: On https://tx-login.ets.org/oaam_server/login.do I am referring to the "userid" and "pass" elements they are the actual text boxes. For some odd reason all elements are not found.

Comment: That wasn't my question :) I am asking about the exact element you are  referring as **STAAR Portal button**

Comment: Sorry about that, the element I am clicking on is this <a href="https://tx-toms.ets.org/" target="_blank" class="button button-alt staar-management-button" title="STAAR Management (opens in new window)">STAAR System</a>

Comment: I kept on looking for the element `<a href="tx-toms.ets.org" target="_blank" class="button button-alt staar-management-button" title="STAAR Management (opens in new window)">STAAR System</a>` within the page https://www.texasassessment.com/ as you mentioned in your question :) which wasn't definitely what you were asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following `xpath` to click.

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='link-group']//a[contains(.,'STAAR System')]")))
element.click();
```

Code here you need to switch to new tab.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.texasassessment.com/administrators/")
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='link-group']//a[contains(.,'STAAR System')]")))
element.click()
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[-1])
username =WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"userid")))
password =WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"pass")))
username.send_keys("username")
password.send_keys("password")
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='loginButton']")))
element.click()
```

Check the snapshot i have just commented last two lines of my code.

[image]

Comment: I mean yeah that helps send me off to the right page, but it doesn't actually send off the user credentials into the portal I need to login. Even after I changed the ID's to match the ID's on the path.

Comment: I checked and it basically just sends a redirect and then redirects again and then times out.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\texasassessment_export.py", line 65, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: No Its redirecting and then passed the value in the input tag and click on sign in button.Can you please run the only code I have provided.

Comment: Yeah I am seeing it work now @KunduK thank you so much, your code is working for me thanks a million!

Comment: In general I guess I wasn't using an explicit wait for the login container. I understand now what I was doing incorrectly. Thank you so much.